# get DragShadow coordinate when dropping it?

Tags: java, android

I want to move the view within a layout, and implement that with API Level 11(startDrag, overwrite View.DragShadowBuilder as shadowView ), but I come across a problem, can not get the actual coordinate when drop view.

I tried to use `getView.getX()`, but it not effective for the value is zero when drop view.

How can I get coordinate when the time drop view?

```
public SimeDragShadowView(View view, Context context) {
        super(view);
        shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
        mDragShadowView = getView();
        mInitX = (int) view.getX();
        mInitY = SimeTabContainer.mDownViewInitY;
        if(DEBUG){
            Log.d(TAG, " shadow button width is .."+getView().getWidth()   +"... height is .."+getView().getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point size, Point touch) {
        // Defines local variables
        if(DEBUG){
            Log.d(TAG, " onProvideShadowMetrics()");
        }
        int width, height;
        width = getView().getWidth();
        height = getView().getHeight();
        shadow.setBounds(mInitX-10, mInitY-10, mInitX + width, mInitY + height);        
        size.set(width, height);
        touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        // Draws the ColorDrawable in the Canvas passed in from the system.
        shadow.draw(canvas);
        getView().draw(canvas);
        if(DEBUG){
            Log.d(TAG, " getView()... x cor is .."+getView().getX());
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem has been solved ,the method i used is ,to listener the event action value 2,and count the event has been received to the dragView, according to the original position and count moveoffsets numbers, i can check the position i drop the view.